# Do I need adjustment if changing to same speed cassette with a wider range of cogs?

Tags: cassette, trainer

I have a Shimano 105 CS-5600 **12-27** 10-speed cassette.  I would like to replace it with a Shimano CS-5700 105 **11-28** 10-speed cassette for my Wahoo trainer. Will this work?  What adjustments might I need if it will work?

Comment: Some additional information could help get a good answer.  Is your rear derailleur also a 105 5600-series model?  Is your Wahoo trainer a wheel-off type (i.e., a Kickr, a Kickr Core) or a wheel-on trainer (i.e., Kickr Snap)?  I assume it is a wheel-off type, but it helps to know for sure.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, this will be fine. The existing chain will likely be long enough as long as it was cut to the normal length following the Shimano instructions. The 5600 rear derailleur is only rated up to 27 but I don’t see this being a problem in practice, though some adjustment of the B screw may be required if the top jockey wheel interferes with the 28t sprocket.